# Fill a array with List data

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

How can I fill a array with the data provided by one List?

For example, I have a List with Strings:

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("a");
l.add("b");
l.add("c");
```

then I want to copy this data into a String array:

```
String[] array = ?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [toArray()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29) method in list...
You have to first allocate an array of an appropriate size (typically list.size()), and then pass it to the toArray method as a parameter. The array will be initialized with the list content.

For example:

```
String[] myArray = new String[myList.size]();
myList.toArray(myArray);
```

You can also do the new call inside the parentheses of toArray

Comment: For safety it should be `myArray = myList.toArray(myArray);`

Comment: @Hardcoded: I've always wondered about that one. Why is there even a return type here? I always hate methods that change their input and return it unless you chain them.

Comment: The method first checks, if the given array is big enough. If it isn't, a new one will created. The only reason for the array parameter is, that there were no information about the type of the array at runtime. It could have been taken a Class-object as well.

Comment: This is minor, but the standard idiom here is to pass in a zero length array of the desired class.  If the list contains 0 elements, it will be returned (0 length arrays are immutable and safe to share). If the list is longer than 0 elements, a new array is created. This is cleaner than creating the array up-front with the desired size.  So String[] myArray = myList.toArray(new String[0]);

Answer (score 7):

First, you have to specify the concrete type of the `List` - `List<String>` (don't leave it raw).

Then, you can do

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`toArray(T[] a)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) method:

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Or alternately:

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

The difference between the two is that the latter *may* not need to allocate a new array.

---

*Effective Java 2nd Edition*: Item 23: Don't use raw types in new code.

[JLS 4.8 Raw Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8)

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. **It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.**

---

Don't make a habit of naming an identifier `l`. It looks an awful lot like `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is a little goofy; you have to provide your own created array as input.

```
String[] array = l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] array = new String[l.size()];
l.toArray(array);
```