# I want to split string without using split function?

Tags: java

I want to split string  without using split . can anybody solve my problem I am tried but
I  cannot find the exact logic.

Comment: Do you want to split using simple delimiter or regular expression delimiter.

Comment: You need to use a loop of some sort. That's probably how split is designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is homework, so I will only give snippets as hints:

#### Finding indices of all occurrences of a given substring

Here's an example of using `indexOf` with the `fromIndex` parameter to find all occurrences of a substring within a larger string:

```
String text = "012ab567ab0123ab";

// finding all occurrences forward: Method #1
for (int i = text.indexOf("ab"); i != -1; i = text.indexOf("ab", i+1)) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "3", "8", "14"

// finding all occurrences forward: Method #2
for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf("ab", i+1)) != -1; ) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "3", "8", "14"
```

#### String API links

- [`int indexOf(String, int fromIndex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

  - Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index. If no such occurrence exists, -1 is returned.

#### Related questions

- [Searching for one string in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940114/searching-for-one-string-in-another-string/)

---

#### Extracting substrings at given indices out of a string

This snippet extracts `substring` at given indices out of a string and puts them into a [`List<String>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
String text = "0123456789abcdefghij";

List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
parts.add(text.substring(0, 5));
parts.add(text.substring(3, 7));
parts.add(text.substring(9, 13));
parts.add(text.substring(18, 20));

System.out.println(parts); // prints "[01234, 3456, 9abc, ij]"

String[] partsArray = parts.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Some key ideas:

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*

  - Works especially nicely if you don't know how many parts there'll be in advance

#### String API links

- [`String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

  - Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.

#### Related questions

- [Fill array with List data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538718/fill-a-array-with-list-data)

Answer (score 11):

Since this seems to be a task designed as coding practice, I'll only guide. No code for you, sir, though the logic and the code aren't that far separated.

You will need to loop through each character of the string, and determine whether or not the character is the delimiter (comma or semicolon, for instance). If not, add it to the last element of the array you plan to return. If it is the delimiter, create a new empty string as the array's last element to start feeding your characters into.

Comment: Your logic helped me not to the above problem but for a different one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do now that most of the java standard libraries are open source

In this case you can start [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

Comment: And probably not pertinent to the question, but it can break the "white paper" syndrome, and offers a glimpse in more realistic codebases than you get in Java101.
Being able to read and follow code in a non-trivial code base is an underrated skill and VERY important.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class tt {
    public static void main(String a[]){
    String s = "012ab567ab0123ab";

    String delims = "ab ";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, delims);
            System.out.println("No of Token = " + st.countTokens());

             while (st.hasMoreTokens())
             {
                 System.out.println(st.nextToken());
             }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String tokenizer to split strings in Java without `split`:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class tt {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        String s = "012ab567ab0123ab";
        String delims = "ab ";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, delims);
        System.out.println("No of Token = " + st.countTokens());
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * My method split without javas split.
 * Return array with words after mySplit from two texts;
 * Uses trim.
 */

public class NoJavaSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text1 = "Some text for example   ";
        String text2 = "   Second sentences     ";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mySplit(text1, text2)));
    }

    private static String [] mySplit(String text1, String text2) {
        text1 = text1.trim() + " " + text2.trim() + " ";
        char n = ' ';
        int massValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text1.length(); i++) {
            if (text1.charAt(i) == n) {
                massValue++;
            }
        }
        String[] splitArray = new String[massValue];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < text1.length(); j++) {
                if (text1.charAt(j) == n) {
                    splitArray[i] = text1.substring(0, j);
                    text1 = text1.substring(j + 1, text1.length());
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return splitArray;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try, the way i did `{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i <str.length();i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)==' ') { // whenever it found space it'll create separate words from string
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    }
    sc.close();
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is: go through the whole string starting from first character and whenever you find a space copy the last part to a new string.. not that hard?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to define the function you need first. In this case, it would probably be:

```
String[] split(String s, String separator)
```

The return type doesn't have to be an array. It can also be a list:

```
List<String> split(String s, String separator)
```

The code would then be roughly as follows:

1. start at the beginning
2. find the next occurence of the delimiter
3. the substring between the end of the previous delimiter and the start of the current delimiter is added to the result
4. continue with step 2 until you have reached the end of the string

There are many fine points that you need to consider:

- What happens if the string starts or ends with the delimiter?
- What if multiple delimiters appear next to each other?
- What should be the result of splitting the empty string? (1 empty field or 0 fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Java standard libraries.

Say the delimiter is `:` and

```
String s = "Harry:Potter"
int a = s.find(delimiter);
```

and then add

```
s.substring(start, a)
```

to a new String array.

Keep doing this till your `start < string length`

Should be enough I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MySplit {

public static String[] mySplit(String text,String delemeter){
    java.util.List<String> parts = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    text+=delemeter;        

    for (int i = text.indexOf(delemeter), j=0; i != -1;) {
        parts.add(text.substring(j,i));
        j=i+delemeter.length();
        i = text.indexOf(delemeter,j);
    }


    return parts.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="012ab567ab0123ab";
    String delemeter="ab";
    String result[]=mySplit(str,delemeter);
    for(String s:result)
        System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WithoutSpit_method {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {

       char[]str;
       String s="Computer_software_developer_gautam";
       String s1[];
       for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;)
       {
       int lengh=s.indexOf("_",i); 
       if(lengh==-1)
       {
           lengh=s.length();
       }
       System.out.print(" "+s.substring(i,lengh));
       i=lengh+1;
       }

    }
}
```

Result: Computer software developer gautam

Comment: kindly explain your answer rather just posting the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of doing with Scanner;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class spilt {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter the String to be Spilted : ");
         String st = input.nextLine();
         Scanner str = new Scanner(st);
         while (str.hasNext())
         {
             System.out.println(str.next());
         }


    }

}
```

Hope it Helps!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringWitoutPre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "md taufique reja";
        int len = str.length();
        char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
        String tmp = " ";
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (ch[i] != ' ') {
                tmp = tmp + ch[i];
                flag = false;
            } else {
                flag = true;
            }
            if (flag || i == len - 1) {
                System.out.println(tmp);
                tmp = " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that all your tokens have " " at the beginning. Why not set `tmp = ""`?

Answer (score 0):

In Java8 we can use Pattern and get the things done in more easy way. Here is the code.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class umeshtest {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        String ss = "I'm Testing and testing the new feature";
        Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(ss).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void splitString(String s, int index) {
        char[] firstPart = new char[index];
        char[] secondPart = new char[s.length() - index];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i < index) {
                firstPart[i] = s.charAt(i);
            } else {
                secondPart[j] = s.charAt(i);
                if (j < s.length()-index) {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(firstPart);
        System.out.println(secondPart);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Split {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static void printArray(String[] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(i!=array.length-1)
            System.out.print(array[i]+",");
            else
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
    static String delimeterTrim(String str){
        char ch = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
        if(ch=='.'||ch=='!'||ch==';'){
            str = str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
        }
        return str;
    }
    private static String [] mySplit(String text, char reg, boolean delimiterTrim) {
        if(delimiterTrim){
            text = delimeterTrim(text);
        }
        text = text.trim() + " ";
        int massValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == reg) {
                massValue++;
            }
        }
        String[] splitArray = new String[massValue];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
                if (text.charAt(j) == reg) {
                    splitArray[i] = text.substring(0, j);
                    text = text.substring(j + 1, text.length());
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return splitArray;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence :");
        String text = in.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("Enter the regex character :");
        //char regex = in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Do you want to trim the delimeter ?");
        String delch = in.next();
        boolean ch = false;
        if(delch.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            ch = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Output String array is : ");
        printArray(mySplit(text,' ',ch));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some text to explain what the code does, how to use it and why you think this answers OP's question...

Answer (score -1):

[Split a string without using split()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGOMK.png)

```
static String[] splitAString(String abc, char splitWith){
    char[] ch=abc.toCharArray();
    String temp="";
    int j=0,length=0,size=0;
    for(int i=0;i<abc.length();i++){
        if(splitWith==abc.charAt(i)){
            size++;
        }
    }
    String[] arr=new String[size+1];
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
        if(length>j){
            j++;
            temp="";
        }
        if(splitWith==ch[i]){
            length++;
        }else{
            temp +=Character.toString(ch[i]);          
        }
    arr[j]=temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arr=splitAString("abc-efg-ijk", '-');

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You cant split with out using split().  Your only other option is to get the strings char indexes and and get sub strings.

Comment: Your second sentence contradicts your first -- that's exactly how you split without using `split()`. It's obviously possible, since `String.split()` is written in Java itself

Comment: Thanks Michael but you did't get what i wrote.  i meant the built split() in function.

Comment: the problem is that that what you wrote is not what you were trying to say.  Trust me ... English has been my first language for > 50 years!  (And BTW - what you were apparently trying to say is a tautology.)