# Searching for one string in another string

Tags: java, string, search

Let's say I have String Table that have a few strings (like mother, father, son) and now in this String Table I want to find every word that contains string "th" for example.

How should I do it? Method string.equals(string) won't help here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [contains](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [indexOf](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) methods, depending on whether you need the position.

Answer (score 11):

The following snippet should be instructive:

```
String[] tests = {
        "father",
        "mammoth",
        "thumb",
        "xxx",
};

String fmt = "%8s%12s%12s%12s%12s%n";
System.out.format(fmt,
    "String", "startsWith", "endsWith", "contains", "indexOf");

for (String test : tests) {
    System.out.format(fmt, test,
        test.startsWith("th"),
        test.endsWith("th"),
        test.contains("th"),
        test.indexOf("th")
    );
}
```

This prints:

```
  String  startsWith    endsWith    contains     indexOf
  father       false       false        true           2
 mammoth       false        true        true           5
   thumb        true       false        true           0
     xxx       false       false       false          -1
```

#### String API links

- [`boolean startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Tests if this string starts with the specified prefix.
- [`boolean endsWith(String suffix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Tests if this string ends with the specified suffix.
- [`boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

  - Returns `true` if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
- [`int indexOf(String s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.

    - `-1` if there's no occurrence

---

#### Finding indices of all occurrences

Here's an example of using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` with the `startingFrom` argument to find all occurrences of a substring within a larger string, forward and backward.

```
String text = "012ab567ab0123ab";

// finding all occurrences forward
for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf("ab", i+1)) != -1; ) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "3", "8", "14"      

// finding all occurrences backward     
for (int i = text.length(); (i = text.lastIndexOf("ab", i-1)) != -1; ) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // prints "14", "8", "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to search a `String` inside another `String`, you would know how to loop in a `String` table. You could use `indexOf` as someone else has suggested or you could use `regex` if it more complex.