# Convert a list of array into an array of array

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list like this:

```
List<MyObject[]> list= new LinkedList<MyObject[]>();
```

and on Object like this:

```
MyObject[][] myMatrix;
```

How can I assign the "list" to "myMatrix"?

I don't want to loop over the list and assign element by element to MyMatrix, but I want to assign it directly (with the oppurtune modifications) if possible.
Thanks

Comment: [stackoverflow.com...fill-a-array-with-list-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538718/fill-a-array-with-list-data) is a nearly a duplicate

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use `toArray(T[])`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] a){ 
        List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[][] matrix=new String[list.size()][];
        matrix=list.toArray(matrix);
    }   
}
```

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: It doesn't compile: "incompatible types; found: array MyObject[], required: array MyObject[][]"

Comment: Actually, try it with a 0 by 0 matrix and it should still work ;)

Comment: you don't need to know the size of the matrix: see for example my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803619/java-convert-a-list-of-array-into-an-array-of-array/5803952#5803952)

Comment: I tried this solution even with some modification to the size of the matrix, but it doesn't compile :(

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have assumed modifying it real quick would break the compile. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it didn't compile.
At end I solved with a loop.

Answer (score 9):

The following snippet shows a solution:

```
// create a linked list
List<String[]> arrays = new LinkedList<String[]>();

// add some trivial test data (note: arrays with different lengths)
arrays.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
arrays.add(new String[]{"d", "e", "f", "g"});

// convert the datastructure to a 2D array
String[][] matrix = arrays.toArray(new String[0][]);

// test output of the 2D array
for (String[] s:matrix)
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/Bcenn)

Comment: Clearer example of the solution

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that we have a list of 'int' array.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList();
```

Now to convert it into 2D array of type 'int', we use 'toArray()' method.

```
int result[][] = list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);
```

We can generalize it further like-

```
List<T[]> list = new ArrayList();
T result[][] = list.toArray(new T[list.size()][]);
```

Here, T is the type of array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray%28%29) or [toArray(T[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method of LinkedList.

Comment: With toArray() the editor says "incompatible types; found: array java.lang.Object[], required: array Item[][]".
I tried to cast the result of toArray() but it give me a ClassCastException

Comment: Did you try the toArray(T []) ?

Comment: @Gressie: +1, good suggestion. By this @Fili might be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item[]> itemLists = new ArrayList<Item[]>();
    itemLists.add(new Item[] {new Item("foo"), new Item("bar")});
    itemLists.add(new Item[] {new Item("f"), new Item("o"), new Item("o")});
    Item[][] itemMatrix = itemLists.toArray(new Item[0][0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemMatrix.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemMatrix[i]));
}
```

Output is

```
[Item [name=foo], Item [name=bar]]
[Item [name=f], Item [name=o], Item [name=o]]
```

assuming that Item is as follows:

```
public class Item {

    private String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converto list to array using. `List.Array()`

Then Use `System.arraycopy` to copy to the 2d array works well for me

```
Object[][] destination = new Object[source.size()][];

System.arraycopy(source, 0, destination, 0, source.size());
```