# Cast List<Object[]> to Object[][] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, classcastexception

How to turn List of arrays into two dimensional array in Java?

```
//Prepare the list
List<Object[]> conf = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
conf.add(new Object[]{ "FOO", "BAR"});
conf.add(new Object[]{ "FOO", "BAR"});
```

I tried:

```
Object[][] array = (Object[][]) conf.toArray(new Object[0]);
```

But it fails at `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java

Comment: The issue is that `Object[]` is an `Object` so a `List<Object[]` becomes an `Object[]` because you passing in an `Object[]` to the method.

Comment: this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803619/java-convert-a-list-of-array-into-an-array-of-array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a pair of square brackets:

```
    Object[][] array = conf.toArray(new Object[0][]);
                                                 ^^
```

Or, if you wish to save on one unnecessary memory allocation:

```
    Object[][] array = conf.toArray(new Object[conf.size()][]);
```

The cast to `Object[][]` is unnecessary once the argument to `toArray()` has the correct type.

Comment: The cast to `Object[][]` is not necessary.