# Convert Queue<Deque<String>> into Object[][] in Java

Tags: java, casting, queue, testng

I'm building a dynamic test with [`@DataProvider` annotation for TestNG](http://sqa-dev.blogspot.com.co/2014/10/testng-data-provider-data-driven.html). In Java, how to convert the data structure defined as `Queue<Deque<String>> queueOfDeques = ArrayDeque<Deque<String>>();` to an `Object[][]`? Based on [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919948/cast-listobject-to-object-in-java), I tried this:

```
@DataProvider( name = "providedQueue" )
public static Object[][] dataForTest(){
        return new Object[][]{{SomeClass.GetQueueOfDeques}};
    }
```

Where the method `GetQueueOfDeques` returns the `queueOfDeques` data structure defined above. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it is not converting the variable as it should be, deriving that TestNG ignores the parameterized test.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.product.migrationtester.ArrayDeque cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: I know it's not my business... but why should you want to downgrade to an Object[][] collection? You will still need to re-cast its content afterwards to be able to access the elements methods :/

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia this is returning type which `@DataProvider` is applicable for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do it by iteration:

```
static Object[][] convert(Collection<? extends Collection<?>> cc) {
    Object[][] res = new Object[cc.size()][]; 
    int i = 0;
    for (Collection<?> c : cc)
        res[i++] = c.toArray();
    return res;
}
```

Such you get general method for converting any collection of collections (they may be `Queue`, `Deque`, `List` and many others) of any type (as `<?>` refers) to `Object[][]` array.

Comment: I changed the `res[i++] = c.toArray();` to `res[i++] = Object[ ] {c}` and worked perfectly. ty so much @sasha-salauyou